# Crystal Reports not Working on IIS 10 and windows server 2019

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019, iis-10

Please someone help!!!

I have Visual Studio 2019 .Net web application that has a button that when clicked it displays a report using crystal reports viewer.

The reports work fine on my development machine. But when I publish my website to IIS 10 a windows 2019 Server, I get the error below.

> An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

I have tried setting the IIS app to enable 32-bit application and configured my visual studio project to run on x86 target platform but none of those things seem to fix the problem. What I am missing? Does someone notice anything missing?

Thank you so much.

Comment: which version of the crystal report you are using? does IIS have permission to the CrytalReportViewer folder?

Comment: You need to install CrystalReportViewer at the server. It's required on the server to show your report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `CrystalReportViewer` at the server. It's required on the server to show your report

Just check the links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C33Q_aNZAyo

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2019/

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SAPSE.CRforVS

If you not found any solution, then write in below forum.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/406514/crystal-report-doesnt-work-in-vs2019.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to check http handler values in web.config file .
Http handler and module are very Important to perform any validation or checks before the request is being processed by server..

In my case after adding http handler values, crystal report started working

Comment: Can you offer an example of what your HTTP Handler value looks like?